# Showing convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $x_1=(1,0,0,...),x_2=(1/2,1/2,0,0,...),x_3=(1/3,1/3,1/3,0,0,0,...),...$

> Show that $x_n$ converges to zero in $\ell ^2$ and $\ell ^{\infty}$ spaces but it doesn’t converge in $\ell ^1$

I have written the sequence as

$(x_i)_n$ =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $ i\gt n$} \\
1/n, & \text{if $i \le n$}
\end{cases}

For  $\ell ^{\infty}$ space :

$\|x_n-0\|_{\infty} = sup_{i \in \mathbb N}|x_{in}| = 1/n \lt \varepsilon$

For  $\ell ^1$ space :

$\|x_n-0\|_{\ell ^1} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_{ni}| = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1/n = 1/n \lt \varepsilon $ since $n$ is independent from index $i$. Thus it converges to zero.

I confused about this. How must I write for $\ell ^1$ space? I cannot see my mistake. Thanks...

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|+\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^\infty |x_i|=n\cdot \frac{1}{n}+0=1$... in other words, the sum of the entries of $x_n$ is always equal to $1$.

Comment: As an aside, one of your simplifications doesn't make sense.  Specifically $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}$.  Remember that the thing on the left is a summation... representing $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\dots$ and is certainly not equal to $\frac{1}{n}$.  That is like saying that $1+1+1+1+1+1+\dots = 1$.  The only number for which that would work is zero since $0+0+0+0+\dots=0$ but the terms in your summation are *not* zero for any finite value of $n$.

Comment: @JMoravitz It is a summation I can understand it but it’s index is $i$ not $n$ namely we can write it without sum like $\sum_{i=1}^n 5i =5 \sum_{i=1}^n i$

Comment: Incorrect.  Look at this one instead, noting that $i$ and $n$ aren't related:  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^a n = n\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^a 1=n\cdot a$.  This is just factorization... $\underbrace{n+n+n+\dots+n}_{a~\text{times}} = n(\underbrace{1+1+1+\dots+1}_{a~\text{times}})=n\cdot a$.  Do not forget that $1$ remains within the summation symbol.  Then look at what happens if $a$ is replaced by $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$|x_n|_{\ell^1}=\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}=1\not\to 0$, while

$|x_n|_{\ell^2}=\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\to 0$.